# How can I use a hash function to generate a value from an interval?

Tags: solidity, dapp-development

So I have a contract that will generate a hash and use that hash as a source of randomness. Now I want to generate a number in a certain interval, which should be evenly distributed.

If the hash (`keccak256`) that I use is 'random' enough, I could just perform a modulo operation.

I am not sure whether `keccak256` is good for that purpose and I also don't know how I can perform the modulo operator on `bytes32` data.

Is it good? And how can I get my number from that data?

Answer (score 1):

Here is just an **example** of how you could take the hash of an input, and convert it into a `uint` to then calculate the modulo:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

contract test{
    function numFromHash(string input, uint range) public pure returns(uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(input))) % range;
    }
}
```

You are right the output of `keccak256()` is `bytes32`, but you can easily [cast it to a `uint`](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.24/types.html#conversions-between-elementary-types).

Unfortunately a function like this is completely predictable, as will be any function which uses data from the blockchain to generate randomness. If there is a big enough prize pool behind this logic, it could potentially be profitable for miners to control or influence the outcome. However, for a lighthearted game or a proof-of-concept, this should work just fine.

Comment: If your result need to be uniformly distributed on the whole range then this algorithm does not works see for example: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/21006/security-concern-about-reducing-hash-value-using-modulo-operation